# Undefined method with coffescript using html event onclick="function()"

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript

I have this line of code in my html

```
<a href="#" onclick="editfuntion(2)">
```

---

And My Coffescript

```
editfunction = (id) ->
  console.log id
  return
```

Why is it it returns ?
Uncaught ReferenceError: editfunction is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Answer (score 1):

Coffeescript will wrap all files in an anonymous function which is immediately executed. This means all variables you define are locally scoped unless explicitly placed in the global namespace (in browsers it is the `window` object, while in NodeJS it's `global`).

---

From [coffeescript.org](https://coffeescript.org/#scripts) (talking about using Coffeescript in a browser, but it also applies to using the Coffeescript compiled to JS ):

> The usual caveats about CoffeeScript apply — your inline scripts will run within a closure wrapper, so if you want to expose global variables or functions, attach them to the window object.

---

Try changing your Coffeescript to:

```
window.editfunction = (id) ->
  console.log id
```

This will expose the function globally on the `window` object so that it can be used within an `onclick` handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
@editfunction = editfunction = (id) ->
    console.log 'Yeheyyy'
```

this will works :)