# Can't access function in another CoffeeScript file?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, coffeescript

I need to set `src` of an image from `background.coffee` for another page but when I call the function to do that from `backround.coffee` I get `view.setScreenshotUrl is not a function`.

```
//background.coffee
views = chrome.extension.getViews()
for view in views
    if view.location.href is viewTabUrl
        view.setScreenshotUrl screenshotUrl
        break

//page.coffee
setScreenshotUrl = (url) -> 
    document.getElementById("target").src = url
```

Comment: inspect the actual compiled js - maybe the function is declared via `const` or `let` in which case it can't be accessed from a different page as per JS specification. It should be a `var` or `window.foo = () -> bar`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined method with coffescript using html event onclick="function()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088803/undefined-method-with-coffescript-using-html-event-onclick-function)

Answer (score 1):

I add the function to the window object like that:

```
window.setScreenshotUrl = (url) -> 
    document.getElementById("target").src = url
```